# How do I disable autocomplete in Apex Oracle 20.2?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am learning SQL and the Udemy course I'm following has us using apex.oracle.com a lot. That site recently updated to version 20.2. Their "New Features" page contains the following:

A new code editor has been implemented throughout the development environment, resulting in a greatly improved code editing experience. The improved editor includes *enhanced code completion*, syntax highlighting and vastly improved accessibility.

This is a LIE. The code editor now constantly tries to suggest things as I'm typing. This is extremely irritating and I can't find a way to disable it. How do I turn off this undesired flashy distracting spam?

Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I feared this may happen. I haven't experienced it yet in 20.2, but typically turn off such features in my text editor and SQL Developer. I hope the pain of adding quotes/brackets to existing code has reduced.

Comment: You have to hit enter twice to skip autofill, if it's up. For example if you're typing the word 'emp' and that's all you want, but it's trying to suggest employees, then hitting enter will clear the popup autofill offer, but won't shift you to a new line. You have to hit enter a second time to do that. This means you have to be watching for that popup to know how many types to hit enter, instead of simply typing.

Answer (score 2):

> This is a LIE

I wholeheartedly disagree with you, and I would also ask of you to be more civil. The new editor contains many enhancements that benefit professional APEX developers, who don't only use it as a SQL playground.

With that being said, I agree that the word-based-suggestions for SQL can be annoying at times. For example, they appear in SQL Commands, but not in Page Designer on pages with implicit suggestions such as page items. I would actually consider this to be a bug.

For APEX 21.1, I would expect there to be many more editor options exposed. For now, this is a workaround for you:

Download the [FOS Browser Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apex-builder-extension-by/jhmmfmhnhnnfnejfphieclbibmoaapid). A small feature of this extension is the injection of (for now) 2 extra editor settings in APEX 20.2 environments. One of them is to enable/disable suggestions completely. Keep in mind that this setting will be stored in local storage, and will be applied globally, so you also won't get page item suggestions in Page Designer.

[image]

Comment: "I would also ask of you to be more civil" I have to disagree. The OP didn't use any swear words and didn't call anybody names. You might concur with the APEX team that the code completion was enhanced, but at least some APEX developers find it terribly annoying (it's driving some of us nuts). Anyway, thanks a ton for the workaround - highly appreciated.